# Is it possible to fly from one sector to another?

Tags: x4-foundations

From looking at the galaxy map, it seems that you should be able to transit from one sector to another without using jump gates, accelerators or highways. When I try flying to the edge of a sector, though, it seems that I can approach the edge but never cross it.

Is it possible to fly from one sector to another directly or are jumps required?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, it's not possible. Travelling between sectors is still done by "Jump Gates", like in X3.

Sources:

Egosoft forums: [Is it possible to fly from Sector to Sector without the use of a Jumpgate?](https://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=401315)

Steam forums: [Flying between sectors? Confused!](https://steamcommunity.com/app/392160/discussions/0/1744479698801392117/?l=latam)

Reddit: [X n00b here. Question about how space travel is handled](https://www.reddit.com/r/X4Foundations/comments/9scqoh/x_n00b_here_question_about_how_space_travel_is/).

Comment: You forgot the most important part: sectors expand when you fly past their initial boundary and become bigger.